# Does Linux Mint have a direct upgrade like Ubuntu

Tags: linux-mint, dist-upgrade

Does Linux Mint have a direct upgrade without a clean install with an USB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, [the Linux Mint upgrade guide](https://linuxmint-user-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/upgrade.html) lists the available upgrade paths and provides links to the corresponding documentation.

In general, you can upgrade from any given release or point release to the latest point release for that major version (*e.g.* 19.1 to 19.3), and from the latest point release for a given major version to the next major version (*e.g.* 19.3 to 20).

Answer (score 2):

Only Linux Mint 20.* (Ulyana, Ulyssa and Uma -not Una-) doesn't have the `mintupgrade` tool. You should use the debian way to upgrade to the next major release version.

To upgrade from Linux Mint Ulyssa to Virginia:

```
sudo sed 's/focal/jammy/g' -i.bak /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list
sudo sed 's/ulyssa/virginia/g' -i.bak.bak /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```